# How to delete first line of text files from Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I need to remove the "content of first line" from 1000's of my text files. I heard it can be done with notepad++ but after browsing for 3 hours (and scratching my head); I am still not able to find a solution to the problem. I have inserted an image URL for better understanding below:

> http://apeee.com/question.jpg

I found that it is possible to do this via Perl (or other languages) but I am not a programmer and have zero programming language. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 7):

Open **all your files** in Notepad++ (please note that you can't open 1000 files at once, you could open the first 100, then the next 100 etc). Go to `Search > Replace` menu (shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) and fill the following:

Find what:

```
^.+?\n(.+)
```

Replace:

```
$1
```

Search mode:

- Select radio button "Regular Expression"
- Select checkbox ". matches newline"

Then press the `Replace All in All Opened Documents`.